# associating plotly graphs and angular JS data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a plotly.js plot with angularJS.

This is the app.js ...

```
var app = angular.module('graphPlotterDemoApp', []);

app.controller('PlotCtrl1', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{
        x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
        y: [10, 15, 12, 17]}];
});

app.directive('linePlot', function () {

    // Create a link function
    function linkFunc(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('data', function (plots) {
            var layout = {
                'width': attrs.width,
                'height': attrs.height,
                'pad':'0',
                'margin': { 't': 0, 'b':20, 'l':40, 'r':0 },
            };

            Plotly.newPlot(element[0], plots, layout);
        });
    }

    // Return this function for linking ...
    return {
        link: linkFunc
    };
});
```

And I have this html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <title>Plotly Graph Plotter Directive for AngularJS - Demo</title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plotly.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="graphPlotterDemoApp">

before div = PlotCtrl1
<div  ng-controller="PlotCtrl1">
    {{data}}
    <table>
    <thead><tr><td>x</td><td>y</td></tr></thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat='x1 in data[0].x'>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='number' ng-model='data[0].x[$index]'></td>
            <td><input type='number' ng-model='data[0].y[$index]'></td>
        </tr>    
    </tbody>
    </table>

    <line-plot width=300, height=200>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The plot appears, but it turns out that when I am changing the value within the input boxes, although the data actually changes, the plot does not change. Is there a way of fixing this?

Comment: Try using $watchCollection or $watch with the objectEquality parameter set to true for complex objects. e.g `$watch('data',function(){},true);`

Comment: Yes! Thanks you!!!! I would never have been able to do it by myself. You can post that as an answer, and Ill be happy to uproot you :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using $watchCollection or $watch with the objectEquality parameter set to true for complex objects. e.g $watch('data',function(){},true);